# Is there any common country to visit for persons holding UK and Schengen visas?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I have a UK visa and my friend has a Schengen visa. Is there any common country where we can meet with our visas?

Comment: The answer may well be probably not, but it would help to know your respective citizenship(s) and the type of visas you have.

Comment: Any common country where? In Europe, given your visas, or further afield?

Answer (score 44):

According to the Mexican consulate in San Francisco, anyone who would otherwise need a visa to visit Mexico is [exempt from that requirement if they have a Schengen or UK visa (among others)](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico):

> effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union).

So Mexico is one option.

I am not going to confirm these others by checking with the official government sources, but according to Wikipedia, the same is true of

- [Albania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Albania)
- [Bosnia and Herzegovina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina)
- [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia)
- [North Macedonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_North_Macedonia)
- [Montenegro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Montenegro)
- [Serbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Serbia)
- [Turkey, with some nationalities excluded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey).

Note that some of these exemptions depend on the fact that the UK is a member state of the European Union, so they may end if the UK leaves the EU.  There also seem to be some other countries that allow visa exemptions for only *some* Schengen and/or UK visa holders, depending on their nationalty.  For example, [Gibraltar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policies_of_British_Overseas_Territories#Gibraltar) accepts UK visas, and it offers a visa exemption to Schengen visa holders only if they are citizens of China, India, Mongolia, Morocco, or Russia.

Comment: +1 for funny answer. Altough probably not what the OP meant :P

Comment: @JorenVandamme whats funny about it?

Comment: @BritishSam at the time he left the comment, the answer only mentioned Mexico, which is indeed probably not what the asker had in mind.

Comment: @BritishSam What phoog said :)
Answer got edited and is less funny now :(

Comment: Gibraltar authorities explicitly say that UK mainland visa are not necessarily valid: *As a general rule, those persons who require a visa for entry into the United Kingdom will also require a **separate** visa for entry to Gibraltar.* Any national, however, can enter through a cruise liner without any visa there.

Comment: @tofro Wikipedia says that Gibraltar offers a visa exemption to "holders of a valid UK multiple entry visa issued for 6 months or more...."  So unless that is wrong *some* UK visas, at least, may be used to enter Gibraltar.  The [government](https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/new/visas-and-immigration) confirms this: "2. The following...do not need a visa for Gibraltar: ... (f) persons holding...a UK multiple entry visa issued for 6 months or more. (g)..."

Comment: @phong Yes, there's an exception for long-stay visa and permanent residence permits.

Comment: @tofro and for multiple-entry visas issued for six months or longer (including visitor visas), as noted in my previous comment.

Answer (score 17):

Provided OP's UK visa is valid for another five days beyond their intended stay, and OP's friend's Schengen visa is either a) a long-term one, or b) a short-term, multiple-entry one with validity for another five days beyond their intended stay, the **Republic of North Macedonia** (formerly known as the former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia) is an option in Europe (the continent).

According to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs, Republic of North Macedonia:

[UK visa holders](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2594&Itemid=1209&lang=en):

> **Entering the Republic of Macedonia with British, Canadian or U.S. visa**
>
> Third country nationals with a valid British, Canadian or U.S. visa with a validity date at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended period of stay in the Republic of Macedonia can stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days at any given entry on the territory of the Republic of Macedonia while the total duration of consecutive stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not exceed 3 (three) months in any six-month period calculated from the day of first entry.

[Schengen visa holders](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=134&Itemid=662&lang=en):

> **Entry in the Republic of North Macedonia for Schengen Visa Holders**
>
> Citizens of the following countries are not required to have entry visa for the Republic of North Macedonia::
>
> [...]
>
> 2. **Third countries with temporary stay in an EU member country or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement**
>
>    may stay up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of North Macedonia and the total amount of the subsequent stays must not be longer than 90 days in any 180-day period.
> 3. **Third countries with permanent stay in an EU member country or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement**
>
>    may stay up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of North Macedonia and the total amount of the subsequent stays must not be longer than 90 days in any 180-day period.
> 4. **Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of North Macedonia.**
>
>    may stay up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of North Macedonia and the total amount of the subsequent stays must not be longer than 90 days in any 180-day period.

---

Note: The Republic of North Macedonia's accession to the EU might change the answer to the above in the future.

Comment: A.K.A. 'The Former Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia'?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo *Formerly* known as the Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia.

Answer (score 1):

Countries in the Middle east

- Qatar(Sure about this)
- UAE

Allow for a transit visa-less access (short duration; 25 hours in my case) when you have a valid Schengen or UK Visa. 
This might be an option worth exploring!

Comment: This answer would be improved if you provide sources for your claims.